# iPhone Telephone App -> Recents -> All/Missed Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

iPhone Telephone App -> Recents -> All/Missed Animation
How can I implement that cell adding/removing animation in my own UITableView? I tried the following:

```
[tableController.aTable beginUpdates];
[tableController.aTable deleteSections:self.sectionIndexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableController.aTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:smartListIndexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableController.aTable endUpdates];
```

But that is not the same animation. I tried all UITableViewRowAnimaiton properties. Non is the exact same one. Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track.  Try unrolling it into separate calls like this and see if that does the trick.

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:0 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:1 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:2 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: but with that i need to change the data source after each delete? or can I put all des deletes inside bein/end Updates?